# Spring + MySQL records being duplicated instead of updated

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, spring-data

In my project I'm migrating data from SQLite db into MySQL db. The problem is that when I migrate multiple times, the already existing records are being duplicated, instead of being updated(in case there are any changes in SQLite, otherwise no action is expected).

**I'm using JpaRepository.saveAll(),  which internally invokes save() for each entity:**

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null.");
    if (this.entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        this.em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return this.em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Then isNew() is invoked but I'm not sure how it compares records in the target db to the ones that are currently being migrated and if that's where the problem occurs at all.

***Do you have any suggestions to solving my problem?***

**That's my entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies")
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
 
  -- properties
  -- constructors/getters/setters/equals/hashcode
}
```

**That's the service that migrates movies(SQLiteMovie is the entity extracted from SQLite, which is then mapped to (MySQL)Movie):**

```
@Service
public class MovieMigrationServiceImpl implements MovieMigrationService {

    private static final int MOVIE_TYPE = 1;

    private final MovieMapper movieMapper;
    private final MovieService movieService;
    private final SQLiteMovieService sqliteMovieService;

    public MovieMigrationServiceImpl(MovieMapper movieMapper, MovieService movieService,
                                     SQLiteMovieService sqliteMovieService) {
        this.movieMapper = movieMapper;
        this.movieService = movieService;
        this.sqliteMovieService = sqliteMovieService;
    }

    @Override
    public String migrateMovies() {
        Collection<SQLiteMovie> sqliteMovies = sqliteMovieService.getAllByMetadataType(MOVIE_TYPE);

        Collection<Movie> movies = mapMovies(sqliteMovies);
        movieService.saveMovies(movies);
        return movies.size() + " movies migrated successfully!";
    }

    private Collection<Movie> mapMovies(Collection<SQLiteMovie> sqliteMovies) {
        return sqliteMovies.stream()
                .map(movieMapper::toMovie)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

**And finally that's the structure of the table in MySQL:**

[image]

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: How are you populating id of entity?

Comment: Try use GenerationType.SEQUENCE instead of GenerationType.IDENTITY.

Comment: @CodeSlave 1) SEQUENCE is not supported by MySQL 2) IDENTITY is the recommended strategy

Comment: @SaurabhSingh I'm not sure if I understand exactly how autogeneration works, but I have annotated Movie's id with GenerationType.IDENTITY and enabled auto-increment for the "id" column of the movies table in MySQL as shown in the screenshot

Comment: It means you are not passing id in entity object so it will be treated as new/transient always. So it will go for persist() instead of merge()

Comment: @SaurabhSingh so the conclusion is that I can't use auto generated ids and expect save() to update existing records, right? I will have to create a custom query I suppose.